# Applying lightbox to enfold

Tags: wordpress

I built a wordpress site using enfold and I have this one page where i want to add a lightbox to a list that has pictures so when clicking them they will open in a lightbox but im a bit afraid to mess up the theme itself, any ideas?
Heres the page: [http://www.rimi.co.il/זרעים/](http://www.rimi.co.il/%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D/)
In the middle of the page theres a few lists with different types of seeds and i want their pictures to open in a lightbox basically

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid to try anything new in wordpress as you have action history on each page there.

You can easily roll back to your page before the changes you applied.

Comment: Tried a few scripts and had no success any other ideas?

Comment: Can you give me more information concerning how you're configuring your lightbox? As far as I know you just need to add it to your page, link it to an image you upload to your site and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about anything, just simply navigate to Enfold theme options >> Scroll sown to Lightbox Modal Window and Check mark it. You're done.

[image]